# JetBrains IDEA: Django ORM support

Tags: django, intellij-idea, autocomplete

IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 does not see Django's Object Manager (`Model.objects`), `Model.DoesNotExists` and `Model.MultipleObjectsReturned`.

[image: Idea screenshot]

Plugins `Python` and `PersistenceFrameworksSupport` are enabled.

Also project interpreter and libraries are setted correctly (autocompletion of statically-defined methods and properties on `Model` available in completion menu).

How to tune IDEA for support of `Model.objects` and other dynamically added properties?

Comment: This probably works only in pycharm

Comment: But it works in idea in different PC. Both has same OS and same Java.

Comment: I think you haven't configured idea properly, because I am using idea in ubuntu/windows. it works fine with autocomplete.